# How to import .svg images with SVGR in Storybook?

Tags: reactjs, svg, webpack, next.js, storybook

I have been trying to begin to use SVG imports in my Storybook stories, but any time I get an error.

[image]

[image]

***.storybook/main.ts***

```
import type { StorybookConfig } from '@storybook/nextjs';

const config: StorybookConfig = {
    stories: ['../src/**/*.mdx', '../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|mjs|ts|tsx)'],
    staticDirs: ['../public'],
    addons: [
        '@storybook/addon-links',
        '@storybook/addon-essentials',
        '@storybook/addon-onboarding',
        '@storybook/addon-interactions',
        {
            name: '@storybook/addon-styling',
            options: {
                sass: {
                    implementation: require('sass'),
                },
            },
        },
    ],
    framework: {
        name: '@storybook/nextjs',
        options: {},
    },
    core: {
        disableTelemetry: true,
    },
    webpackFinal: async (config: any) => {
        if (config.resolve) {
            config.module.rules.unshift({
                test: /\.svg$/i,
                issuer: /\.[jt]sx?$/,
                use: ['@svgr/webpack'],
            });
        }

        return config;
    },
};
export default config;
```

What is the problem and how to solve it ?